# How to disallow access to a subdomain using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using this web hosting company that thinks that providing a web access to my email settings would be a "good idea". So basically if my site is `example.com`, a URL like `http://mailboxes.example.com` will open up a login page for that. So I was wondering if there's a way to disable anything within the `mailboxes` subdomain via `.htaccess`? (Or maybe redirect it.)

So far I tried doing the redirection:

```
# Prevent webmail access
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mailboxes\.example\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/contactme  [L,R]
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything and the page still loads.

**EDIT:** Guys, here's full `.htaccess` file in case that makes a difference:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Define priority of which index file is used first
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html

# Error pages:
ErrorDocument 401 /err401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /err403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /err404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /err500.php

# Prevent opening directory listings from the web
Options -Indexes

# Prevent 'error_log' from being accessed from the web:
RewriteRule (^|/)error_log$ - [L,R=404]

# Redirect access to mailboxes subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mailboxes\.example\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/contactme/  [L,R]

# Prevent .ini and other files from being open from web browser
<filesMatch ".*\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</filesMatch>

<filesMatch "phprc$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: it is happening because of your `.htaccess ` will never be executed.
the subdomain directly points some other directory
so what you have to do is make a `.htaccess` where your subdomain is pointing and redirects it to your desired domain.

Comment: Oh, OK. That explains it. So I'm pretty much stuck with it. hah?

Comment: no if you have the domain control panel access then you can change the directory of that subdomain.

Comment: does contactme is page ? or directory?

Comment: @MohammedElhag: It's a dir with an `index.php` that loads my `contact me` page.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit: It's a strange looking CP. I've never seen such before. Anyhow, I don't see that `mailboxes` subdomain as listed anywhere in their CP.

Comment: then this subdomain entry might be in the domain provider account